# FastAPI: output should be list of lists, but it gives and error about dict... 'value is not a valid dict'

Tags: python, fastapi

I looked at other posts that seems to have similar errors, but they don't seem to be specific to list of lists output. Here is the code:

```
@app.post('path/to/file.py', response_model = List[list_data])
async def function_list_data(something):
    output = data.function_list_data(a = 1, b = 2)
    return output

#> Error: response -> #
    value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)
```

I've tried many variations and suggestions from other posts. I also tried `response_model = List[List[list_data]]` but no luck. I don't understand why it's giving me an error about dict.

Comment: What is `output`? What is the definition of `list_data`? You can't give any random data and expect Pydantic or FastAPI to be able to solve it for you; You'll have to return it in a compatible format, create your own response or configure the Pydantic model (`list_data`) to be able to load content in a specific way.

Comment: @MatsLindh Right -- `output` is a list of lists. `list_data` is defined as a response model class with two outputs (date and string, if that helps) contained within a list. So `output` looks like this: `[[date, string], [date, string], ...]`

Comment: You can't initialize a Pydantic model from a list (it wouldn't have any idea what value maps to date and which maps to str; changing the model would also break code in mysterious way). It needs to be something that defines a name, so something like a named tuple, a dictionary, a database ORM object, etc (`orm_mode` on your model allows Pydantic to use properties for values as well (so `.foo` and not just `['foo']`).

Comment: @MatsLindh Hmm I see. Would I still be able to use a list to make an output of multiple values? I was thinking list of dictionaries, but unsure if that would work. How would you do it?

Comment: `return [{'date_field_name_in_model': row[0], 'string_field_name_in_model': row[1]} for row in output]` - that way you'll get proper documentation for the endpoint (the `List[list_data]` part), don't have to modify your internal API (unless you need this code in multiple places, then either modify it if possible or create an helper function that does this) and can adapt it in your view function as necessary (but again, if you need this in multiple locations, restructuring code will be a better solution)